# How to get rid of black box in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, artboard

I'm trying to work with this photo in Illustrator CC, but there is this black box in the center of the page. I tried ignoring it but when I save my image, it only saved whats in the black box....yet I can't seem to decrease the size to just the box. I'm sure there is a very simple reason for this but I can't figure it out. I'm self taught with Adobe so some basic things have been caught later on (and usually when I'm under a deadline). [image]

Comment: Thank you! I know this is an elementary question but...for the sake of guessing-I basically either need to reduce the image to fit OR increase the size of my artboard, yes?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Select the photo.

Choose `Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork`

The "black box" is your artboard (canvas).

Comment: alternatively one can resize the picture to fit the artboard size...

Answer (score 1):

@scott is right, this is your artboard. Just a little bit more information as per your comment: if you want to keep the size of the image, you want to change the size of the artboard.

You can do this by finding the artboard button:

[image]

...and then either:

- double click on your image (should there be more than one element,
  you might have to group them first).
- use the handles on the artboard to alter the size manually.

[image]